# Unable to ping gateway after OpenStack installation

Tags: bridge, openstack

I configured openstack with packstack and after configuring it is not possible to ping the gateway of the interface that I created openstack on. Is it because of the bridges that openstack creates? How can I fix this issue?

This is the result of ip a:

```
1: Lo: «LOOPBACK, UP, LOWER UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default glen 1000
Link/Loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid lft forever preferred lft forever
Inet6 :: 1/128 scope host
valid lft forever preferred lft forever
2 : em1: <NO-CARRIER, BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP> mtu 1500
link/ether 90:b1: 1c:12:ec:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
gaisc ma state DowN group default qlen 1000
inet 192.168.137.45/24 brd 192.168.137.255 scope global dynamic em1
valid lft 603019sec preferred lft 603019sec
inet6 fe80::92b1:1cff: fe12:eccd/64 scope link valid lft forever preferred lft forever
3: em2: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST, SLAVE, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bonde state UP group default qlen 1000
Link/ether 90:b1: 1c: 12:ec:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff: ff
4: em3: «NO-CARRIER, BROADCAST, MULTICAST, SLAVE, UP> mtu 1500 qdisc ma master bonde state DOWN group default qlen 1
Link/ether 90:b1:1c:12:ec:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: em4: «NO-CARRIER, BROADCAST, MULTICAST, SLAVE, UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bonde state DOWN group default qlen 1
000
link/ether 90:b1:1c:12:ec:ce brd ff:ff:ff: ff: ff:ff
10: bonde: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST, MASTER, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master ovs-system state UP group defa ult quen 1000
link/ether 90:b1:1c:12:ec:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.16.8.2/24 brd 172.16.8.255 scope global bonde
valid lft forever preferred lft forever
inet6 fe80::92b1:1cff: fe12:ecce/64 scope Link valid lft forever preferred lft forever
28: ovs-System: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 1a:e8:4b:36:16:5d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
29: br-ex: «BROADCAST, MULTICAST> mtu 1500 9d15 noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 90:b1:1c:12:ec:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
30: br-int: «BROADCAST, MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc
noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 1a:32:8a:df:6a:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

And this is the result of ovs-vsctl list-br:

```
$ sudo ovs-vsctl list-br
br-ex
br-int
```

and this is in the answer file:
CONFIG_NEUTRON_OVS_BRIDGE_IFACES=br-ex:bond0

I am unable to ping 172.16.8.1 which is the gateway address. bond0 and em2 have the same IP address and gateway.